# Can arrays inside functions be initialized with the return value of functions?Is "int arr[2]={strcmp("a","a"),strcmp("3","5")};" correct?

Tags: c, arrays, function, constants, array-initialization

Aren't only variables of static storage type expected not to be initialized with return values of functions as those are not considered constants?Going by that argument,isn't the following declaration valid in C.It compiles without error or warning,and output is as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main ()
{
   int arr[2]={strcmp("a","a"),strcmp("3","5")};
  printf("%d,%d",arr[0],arr[1]);
}
```

`Result`   **0,-1**

Comment: This is self explanatory.  any array followed b y = { will set the array indexes to values.  strcmp returns the difference between the strings, so that's what gets put in the array.  Its not static because its in the main stack frame.

Comment: Nitpicky, it should be `int main(void)`. Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with the code. (The output may be different, getting `0,-2` would be another common output. All that the standard guarantees is that `arr[1]` is negative.)

Answer (score 0):

The statement that static variables can not bet initialized with return values of functions is true, but in your exemple, arr is not a static variable, but variable stored on the stack, so this piece of code is totally valid.

On the other hand, writting:

```
static int arr[2]={strcmp("a","a"),strcmp("3","5")};
```

would be illegal, for the reasons you explained.